# Jquery lie about size of download

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

When you go to jquery.com you see on top right
"Grab the latest version!
Choose your compression level:"
its saying 32Kb for Production (compressed) version in reality when you download it its 91Kb. Go figure if they forgot to update it or want to mislead people who new to it into that its compact thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information they are providing is right because the gzipping happens on the server that gives the file.

The server you are using has to be configured to allow gzipped version of javascript files.
The version from Google CDN is already gzipped.

Comment: i tested that and its true, but however they should have said that.

Comment: yes you are right, they should mention it somewhere to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading why jQuery is actually a great framework to use. But you can be stubborn and write pure javascript the long hard way the rest of your life. Why not download the uncompressed version of jQuery and minify it yourself?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6844893/804087

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67079/804087